# Informatica workflow scenario

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a question regarding workflows in our case everytime we copy the same workflow it just that we change the parameter file and naming convention of workflow.Session in workflow is reusable.I dont want to create reusable workflow .Is there anyway that we can create multiple workflows at once with different naming conventions and create different param files.My main focus is to automate this process so that we can create 50 workflows in one shot and create param files dynamically.Please let me know if its possible?

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple workflows. Just run the same workflow with different parameter files.

Comment: Like Samik said, you can run workflows from command line with different parameter files. Example  Run 1 : wf_1 param1.txt Run 2 : wf_1 param2.txt. In this case you don't need to create multiple workflows

Comment: We need to create different workflows due to linkage of job run with other stuffsI know the concurrent workflow property but we cant use it due to linkage with other objects thats why i am asking this question. Isnt it any way we can automate copy process of workflows like we need to just change the name of workflow and parameter file dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isnt a valid query. If you still want to give it a try then what you can do is at first export that workflow to some xml and use this same xml with `pmrep` command to import with new name.

```
     pmrep objectexport -n 
      <DB.SourceName> -o 
    Source -f <Folder Name> -m -s -b -r –u 
     <xml file name>;

     ---------xml details to be included----------

      <RESOLVECONFLICT>

         <TYPEOBJECT 
      RESOLUTION="RENAME" 

   OBJECTTYPENAME="WORKFLOW"/>

     </RESOLVECONFLICT>
```

but again I will say your query is pointless coz you have it manually just to drag and drop that workflow onto same existing folder and rename even if you want to create many workflows

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to automate the creation of workflows in informatica. But since you want to invoke the same workflow with the same session, but you have different parameter files, you could probably use the pmcmd command and specify different parameter names at the time of invocation.